# Get a list of columns updated by a trigger

Tags: triggers, firebird, firebird2.5

I need to display all the table columns which are updated by the triggers.

I have checked with below query but its showing only the table name, but I need table columns as well.

```sql
SELECT * FROM RDB$TRIGGERS WHERE RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG=0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple query which allows you to identify the columns which were updated by a trigger. You will need to inspect (or, if you want to automate it, parse) the trigger code from column `RDB$TRIGGER_SOURCE` to see which columns are assigned new values in the trigger code. Alternatively, you could parse the BLR (the compiled form) of the trigger from column `RDB$TRIGGER_BLR` to see which columns are updated, but that will take some work on your part to write a a suitable parser of the BLR.